# How to issue tokens from MVC web app for Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to figure out if this is an anti-pattern or if this is a valid way to do things.

I have an MVC5 web app that accesses a Web API. I manage identity via ASP.NET identity 2 via the MVC app.

I'm trying to figure out how to issue an OAUTH2 bearer token from the MVC app to send to the Web API, and then how to access the claims from the token in the API.

I'm assuming as long as the app and the API share a machine key that I can somehow decrypt the token at the API (correct me if I am wrong), but how do Icorrectly issue a token from the app? Is it fair to assume that I can just use OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions to create a token endpoint on the MVC app, then get the token from here prior to calling the Web API?

All of this makes sense to me, I'm just looking for reassurance that this is the right, or accepted way to do things in this scenario.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm attempting to solve a similar problem right now.